# How can I encode characters in a URL for an ASP.NET WebAPI confirm email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI application than needs to create a link for a confirmation email.  Here's the code for it:

```
 callbackUrl1 = "http://localhost:2757/index.html" +
                "?load=email" +
                "&userId=" + user.Id +
                "&code=" + code;
 await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(
    user.Id, 
    "Confirm your account", 
    "Please click this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl1 + "\">link</a>");
```

My code is almost working but it seems like I need to encode the data that goes into the query string.

With MVC this was done like this:

```
 var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", 
     "Account", 
     new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, 
     protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

However I am not using MVC and when I tried adding it I got a number of unrelated problems.

Can someone tell me how I can encode (if that's the right word) the data that goes up to make the link?

Comment: Create it as a Systyem.Uri

Comment: what about `userId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(user.Id)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Note that you still need to HTML encode the URL for the HTML of the e-mail

Comment: You can do the whole callbackUrl1 by creating a URI and using the AbsoluteUri property.

Comment: You certainly could but then you have to create an object and put it back in a string. It seems like a matter of preference to me.

Comment: Fair enough, the static will get you there quicker, the Uri easier. I would say the more parameters you have in the query string the more preferable the Uri approach becomes for me. Unless you are designing 110% for performance.

Comment: I actually agree. The question is where does 2 stand as a number of parameters :)

Comment: For 2, probably on the HttpUtility.UrlEncode in my books. Hope I just made your day :)

Comment: The maximum of the function which evaluates how appropriate a method for encoding URLs is based on the number of parameters does not affect the general feeling of my day but thank you. It was a fine day, hope you have at least as good.

Answer (score 2):

Encode the URL using System.Uri  [Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L4G903)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var callbackUrl1 = new System.Uri("http://localhost:2757/index.html" +
                "?load=email" +
                "&userId=" + "12345££&^" +
                "&code=" + "myCo   de");


        var aHref = string.Format("<a href=\'{0}'>link</a>", callbackUrl1.AbsoluteUri);


        Console.WriteLine(aHref);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest this value for code
' onclick=function(){ alert("pwned"); } data-dummy='
(the single quotes included). Of course in this particular case code is probably generated by ASP.NET Identity but in general you need to HTML encode in this case.

Comment: Depends where the userID and code are coming from. If from inputs on the web form, then you need to take necessary action to prevent injection. There are various ways of doing this depending on your requirements.

Comment: It is interesting if in this case it is needed. Now obviously there is no chance that ASP.NET Identity will generate code that is actual injection but it may generate a single quote and break things.